# setState inside useEffect doesnt update UI

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-effect

i am trying to fetch multiple endpoints in UseEffect and depending on it's result show data on the UI (avatar, username, etc.)

Problem is, that the data received in the `fetch()` calls inside `useEffect` do in fact return the correct data but when trying to access it in the UI-Code, it will not show up.

As you can see in my code, I have the isLoading state, but I feel like the `then` operation doesnt really wait until the response is there.. The loading screen will be shown for 0.5 sec but when the normal screen pops up, username, avatar, etc. are empty.

So how can I make the UI wait until `useEffect` has completely loaded the data and then display it?

`UserProfile.tsx`

```js
  React.useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem(LOGGED_IN_USER).then((userSteamID) =>
      fetch(USER_PROFILE + userSteamID)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => json.steamId)
        .then((steamId) => {
          fetch(USER_INVENTORY + steamId)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((json) => {
              console.log(json);
              setProfileInfo(json);
              setSteamID(json.steamId);
              setInventoryValue(json.value);
            })
            .catch((err) => alert(err))
            .finally(() => setLoading(false));
        })
    );
  }, []);
```

trying to use it afterwards:

```
  if (loading) {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          height: "100%",
          justifyContent: "center",
          backgroundColor: Colors.dark.background,
        }}
      >
        <ActivityIndicator
          size="large"
          style={{ backgroundColor: Colors.dark.background }}
        />
        <Text
          style={{
            color: Colors.dark.text,
            marginTop: 10,
            alignSelf: "center",
          }}
        >
          retrieving userdata...
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <Text>{inventoryValue}</Text> // avatar, etc. wont work as well
)
```

I Navigate from a `LoginScreen.tsx` to it like so:

```
  onPress={async () => {
          let result = await startAuth();
          if (result.type == "success") {
            setLoggedInUser(result.steamID);
            console.log("ID: " + result.steamID);
            navigation.navigate("UserProfile");
          }
```

Comment: which react version are you using?

Comment: my `package.json` states 1.0.0

Comment: I'm asking about react dependency version?

Answer (score 0):

Create promise chain

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  AsyncStorage.getItem(LOGGED_IN_USER).then((userSteamID) =>
    fetch(USER_PROFILE + userSteamID)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => json.steamId)
      .then((steamId) => fetch(USER_INVENTORY + steamId))
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        setProfileInfo(json);

        // This can be avoided, already available in profileInfo
        setSteamID(json.steamId); 
        setInventoryValue(json.value);       
      })
      .catch((err) => alert(err))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false))
  );
}, []);
```

With async/await

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  const init = async () => {
    try {
      const userSteamID = await AsyncStorage.getItem(LOGGED_IN_USER);
      const { steamId } = await fetch(USER_PROFILE + userSteamID).then((r) =>
        r.json()
      );
      const json = await fetch(USER_INVENTORY + steamId).then((r) => r.json());
      setProfileInfo(json);

      // This can be avoided, already available in profileInfo
      setSteamID(json.steamId);
      setInventoryValue(json.value);
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };
  init();
}, []);
```

Comment: doesnt work unfortunately..

Comment: @codedor which react version are you using?

Comment: react-native --version returns: 

```react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.64.3```